# can we use widget data inside the initState?

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

Below is a code snippet of the Calendar stateful class I made.My question is, can I access the eventDateList inside the initState below as "widget.eventDateList"?!

```
class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<DateTime> eventDateList;
  final void Function(DateTime, List<Event>) onDayPressed;
  final DateTime selectedDate;
  bool isReserved;

 Calendar(
    {required this.eventDateList,
    required this.onDayPressed,
    required this.selectedDate,
    this.isReserved = false});

  @override
   _CalendarState createState() => _CalendarState();
  }

class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
  DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.now();
  String _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(DateTime.now());
  DateTime _targetDateTime = DateTime.now();

  EventList<Event> _markedDateMap=new EventList<Event>(
     events: {},
   );

   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can access in initstate as follows:

```
 @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
print(widget.eventDateList);

     }
```